# Why is my view running extremely slow in comparison to the regular query?

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql server view that has a number of joins in there. These joins are pulling and comparing records of 60,000+ when aggregating all three tables. The problem is the view takes 1.5 hours to run in comparison to the regular query which is maybe 2-5 mins. I tried using paging and same results so I am not sure what else to do at this point.

Here is a copy of the code in the view which I tested in the query also:

```sql
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[dashboardview]
WITH SCHEMABINDING 

AS
SELECT         o.ID, o.Name, o.DateRan, s.Name AS Job, o.Start, o.[End], o.Status, o.Logs 
FROM            dbo.output AS o LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                         dbo.jobs AS j ON o.Job = j.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.scripts AS s ON  j.Script = s.ID 
Where o.DateRan < GETDATE()

ORDER BY o.ID DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY
GO
```

Any thoughts on what I can do to optimize this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96220/discussion-on-question-by-robdigm-why-is-my-view-running-extremely-slow-in-compa). Please keep your question up to date (by editing it) with new information revealed through the chat. Cheers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned by OP.